# Using sonar in pretty big team

Tags: sonarqube

We have something about 20 people in our team and we are using sonar for now to analyse new code before submiting it to the main stream. So each designer uses it's own Sonar installed on his machine.

What I'm trying to do is to create a one instance of the Sonar which each designer will be able to use. The only concern I have is what will happen if:

1. One designer will launch analysis on one revision of file and right after that the second designer will launch analysis on another revision of this file (in the worst case we can have a bunch of such a files). First designer won't be able to see his violations and won't be able to see code he wrote at all. Do we have some mechanism to overcome this?
2. What will happen if two designers will analyse the same project at the same time? AFAIK, Sonar won't allow them to do so. Any workaround for this?

Of course, we can, somaehow, create a project on the sonar side for each team member, but this has it's drawbacks, such as issues, marked as false positive in one proect won't appear as such an issues in another project and so on.

Any ideas on such an issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want to set up is:

- a central Sonar instance that analyses the code base on a regular basis (for instance every day) based on the code located in the repository. This instance should be the reference and the project manager(s) will use it to monitor the project.
- ask the developers to run local analyses before commiting their code:

  - either using Sonar Eclipse if you're coding in Java, C++ or Python. Everything is perfectly described in the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+Sonar+in+Eclipse), more precisely the ["Checking code prior to commit" section](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Working+with+Sonar+in+Eclipse#WorkingwithSonarinEclipse-CheckingCodePriortoCommit)
  - or using the [Issues Report plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Report+Plugin) if your language is not supported yet in Sonar Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, Fabrice! The thing is, that we have such a structure for now and "central" Sonar is on product owner side and we have no access to it. What I want to set up is local centralized Sonar not to make designers update plugins, solve Sonar issues and update Sonar itself. BTW, is it possible to create separate project on Sonar side for each designer for analysis of similar source code?

Comment: You can recreate what I described on a local centralized Sonar without any issue - as long as you have a dedicated server for that. If you want to have separate project for each developer, they can run analyses using the "sonar.branch" property. For instance, M. Foo can run "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=MisterFoo".